# Light Beams effect

Tags: node-editor, light

My problem is pretty compicated.
I want to make effect like this [image: Light Beams]

(this is not render;) )
I've found some useful tutorials, but i can't make it "scale friendly".
First of all, i have principled volume shader, than grandient textures to have fading effect, and a bit of noise texture to give it more random scatter. But all the setting are just fine for one scale, and after scaling up the end of the cone, i have strange effects.

Maybe someone have better results, with less amount of nodes?

I though about using spot light in the volumetric box, but with no result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about the Sun Beams filter in Compositing?

Comment: This image is not my render. It's just an image witch shows what kind of effect i need. I wrote it under the image that it is not a render.

Answer (score 3):

No real experience but it looks like the Sun Beam filter in Compositing would do the trick.

I created 2 simple spotlights (filled circles) using emission shader with a strongly contrasted noise texture. Positioned two Sun Beams filter close to the spotlights on the final rendering. The compositing is really basic but I am sure it can be tuned to something pretty close to what you are looking for.

Note the undesired side effect of the sun beams acting on the opposite side spotlight. This could be avoided with a horizontal mask applied to each Sun Beam.

[image]

You could use a star shaped black and white mask for the spotlight to match the spot pattern desired...